# Error is jsonp response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

i am using the following code to call the public api to get earthquake data
using ajax and jsonp. i tried different methods but i am unable to resolve the error in the code below

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp?jsonerror=t&callback=localJsonpCallback",
         jsonp: "localJsonpCallback",
         dataType: "jsonp",

        data:'',
        success: function( response ) 
        {
            console.log( response ); // server response
        }
    });
function t(response) 
 {
     console.log( response );
     }

 function localJsonpCallback(response) 
 {
        if (!response.Error) 
        {
            console.log( response ); 
        }
        else 
        {
            alert(response.Message);
        }
    }
```

but i am getting the following error

jquery-latest.js:9803 GET http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp?j…allback&callback=jQuery111108420504496052599_1476799978359&_=1476799978360 403 (Forbidden) and i know these api's are public

Answer (score 0):

The server is returning the response with status code 403 Forbidden for your request. There's not much you can do in this regard.

Doing some testing I realised that if you omit all the query parameters, the server responds properly with http 200 OK.

That's probably some security implementation on their end. Is there any way you can do this without using JSONP? I'm not sure if they will block it or not, but you can try using ["CORS"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). That way you would be able to make the request without the need for querytring parameters.